# How to make only ON data in my form show up in the results?

Tags: cognito-forms

I am making a menu for my client to submit weekly with their selections for that week. I am including all of the meals that I make for them and they will check the box of the meals they want. With each selection, it gives them the option to make changes or substitutions or add notes. I've got all of that down.

Here's my dilemma: when the form comes to me in email, every single item that is on the form is emailed with either yes or no.  I ONLY want any that are checked to be emailed to me and I can't seem to find the option to do that.  This way, the email comes with only the meals they want listed with the changes and I can print it off and go without having to look at the whole email and pick out the data that I want.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the submission settings of the Build tab, at the way bottom of the screen click on submission settings.
Then click inside the white box where it says Notification settings.
Another window will pop up, uncheck the box that says "Include Blank Fields?"
click Save. 
This should resolve your issue and only provide the data that was filled out in the form.